# ADFS on Opera and BlackBerry does not work?

Tags: .net, opera, single-sign-on, adfs

Is it possible to make ADFS work on Opera and/or Blackberry. I am getting error:

> Your client is incapable of Basic Authentication, or you supplied a
>   bad user name or password.

On Firefox/Chrome/Android/IE everything is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

Opera/Blackberry aren't listed as tested browsers as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678034(v=WS.10).aspx

However, one option is to force forms based auth for everyone by making forms the preferred handler. This method should allow any browser to support AD FS.

You'd end up editing the web.config to look like below

```
<localAuthenticationTypes>
  <add name="Forms" page="FormsSignIn.aspx" />
</localAuthenticationTypes>
```

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895365.aspx for more details.

This however means no integrated authentication for any corpnet machines that are likely using the AD FS server.